# XSD Date with attribute but optional value

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

How do I an XSD date value which is optional? Is there a way I could escape from using nillable?

For instance, both

```
<element attribute="attribute">optional-value</element>
<element attribute="attribute"/>
```

are valid types, where "optional-value" must be defined as an xsd:date type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but not with something that tools like:

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="root">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:simpleContent>
                <xsd:extension base="EmptyDate">
                    <xsd:attribute name="attribute" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
                </xsd:extension>
            </xsd:simpleContent>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:simpleType name="EmptyDate">
        <xsd:union memberTypes="xsd:date emptyString"/>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="emptyString">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:length value="0"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Invalid XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Sample XML generated by QTAssistant (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" attribute="attribute1" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"> </root>
```

Valid XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Sample XML generated by QTAssistant (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" attribute="attribute1" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"/>
```

Comment: When I unmarshalled this using JAXB, the "optional-value" component was unmarshalled as a String type instead of the default XML Date type - XMLGregorianCalendar. Is there something else I need to change?

Comment: It is because of the empty string you're getting this behaviour... If you don't want this, then you're stuck with nillable.

Comment: Thanks, I found out from the JAXB guide that the default behaviour for unmarshalling xs:union types is String, and the need to convert to any other type needs to be handled programmatically

Comment: You can also import the XForms schema, which defines those types for you, e.g. in this case `xf:date`. See: http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/Forms/2007/XForms-11-Schema.xsd